# OCaml time profiling on OS X

Tags: profiling, ocaml

In the absence of a working gprof, what other tool can I use to profile on OS X?

(I know about the poor man's approach but would prefer something that does not require manual code instrumentation)

I have so far refrained from installing the full Xcode and tried using Activity Monitor but I am not sure I am doing things right?

Details:
I have managed to compile my project for time profiling using ocamlbuild and the ".p.native" build target. I then use Activity Monitor on Mac OS X 10.9 to sample the running process. This gives a whole lot of output about OCaml internals such as garbage collection but I am not seeing properly annotated function names from my module.

A fragment of the output:

```
Call graph:
    2109 Thread_55861   DispatchQueue_1: com.apple.main-thread  (serial)
      542 .L1099  (in atest.p.native) + 18  [0x101a89956]
      + 210 caml_weak_get  (in atest.p.native) + 278  [0x101ac79e6]
      + ! 87 caml_alloc_small  (in atest.p.native) + 22  [0x101ab75e6]
      + ! : 70 mcount  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 32,37,...  [0x7fff87545620,0x7fff87545625,...]
      + ! : 10 mcount  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 59  [0x7fff8754563b]
      + ! : | 10 moncount  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 0,1,...  [0x7fff8754d3a5,0x7fff8754d3a6,...]
      + ! : 7 DYLD-STUB$$moncount  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 0  [0x7fff875c549e]
      + ! 68 caml_alloc_small  (in atest.p.native) + 1,128,...  [0x101ab75d1,0x101ab7650,...]
      + ! 46 caml_alloc_small  (in atest.p.native) + 87  [0x101ab7627]
      + ! : 40 caml_minor_collection  (in atest.p.native) + 90  [0x101ab624a]
```

I see a lot of symbols similar to .L1099 above but almost none that have a proper name of the type  `Module-name_function-name_unique-number` which is what I expect from reading the OCaml manual. Confusingly a few symbols do appear that are human readable - but not enough to be useful.

Another fragment in which the very last line is a function from my own module

```
Sort by top of stack, same collapsed (when >= 5):
        mcount  (in libsystem_c.dylib)        617
        caml_weak_get  (in atest.p.native)        256
        caml_alloc_small  (in atest.p.native)        97
        caml_modify  (in atest.p.native)        94
        moncount  (in libsystem_c.dylib)        93
        caml_c_call  (in atest.p.native)        67
        mark_slice  (in atest.p.native)        42
        caml_weak_set  (in atest.p.native)        36
        caml_page_table_lookup  (in atest.p.native)        34
        camlRandom__bits_1038  (in atest.p.native)        30
        sweep_slice  (in atest.p.native)        24
        DYLD-STUB$$mcount  (in atest.p.native)        23
        DYLD-STUB$$moncount  (in libsystem_c.dylib)        18
        compare_val  (in atest.p.native)        16
        .L327  (in atest.p.native)        15
        .L621  (in atest.p.native)        15
        .L1202  (in atest.p.native)        14
        .L1205  (in atest.p.native)        14
        .L1173  (in atest.p.native)        12
        .L1113  (in atest.p.native)        11
        .L1281  (in atest.p.native)        11
        .L1310  (in atest.p.native)        11
        caml_fl_allocate  (in atest.p.native)        11
        caml_oldify_one  (in atest.p.native)        11
        caml_weak_blit  (in atest.p.native)        11
        .L1099  (in atest.p.native)        10
        .L1150  (in atest.p.native)        10
        .L135  (in atest.p.native)        10
        .L149  (in atest.p.native)        10
        .L295  (in atest.p.native)        10
        caml_alloc_shr  (in atest.p.native)        10
        .L148  (in atest.p.native)        9
        .L268  (in atest.p.native)        9
        invert_pointer_at  (in atest.p.native)        9
        .L1135  (in atest.p.native)        8
        .L1154  (in atest.p.native)        8
        .L1278  (in atest.p.native)        8
        allocate_block  (in atest.p.native)        8
        .L1114  (in atest.p.native)        7
        .L1118  (in atest.p.native)        7
        .L1172  (in atest.p.native)        7
        .L131  (in atest.p.native)        7
        camlReact__occurs_1470  (in atest.p.native)        7
        camlReactor__compare_1235  (in atest.p.native)        7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A usable solution is the [landmarks](https://github.com/LexiFi/landmarks) library which allows manual or automatic instrumentation of code and incorporates CPU cycle counters, allocation info from the GC and wall clock timing. Works fine on OS X and allows fine-grained profiling where necessary.

Answer (score 1):

[Poor man's profiler](http://poormansprofiler.org/) doesn't require any code instrumentation at all. See this [example of usage](https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/caml-list/2011-08/msg00050.html), albeit for allocation profiler but the idea is the same.

`<shameless plug>`You can also use ready-made [pmp](https://github.com/ygrek/scraps/blob/master/pmp) script.`</shameless plug>`

Comment: Point taken. What I meant to say is manual data collection - I would like just to get a ready-made list of functions and the time spent in them, for convenience. But maybe the bash script actually does that for me?

Comment: ok, i tried the pmp script. since gdb is not included on os x or xcode, this required installing gdb via homebrew, creating a certificate and self-signing it. i followed [this guide](http://ntraft.com/installing-gdb-on-os-x-mavericks/). unfortunately, when running the script, the process info in /proc/<PID>/exe is not found. os x does not seem to use that. so, the answer does not seem to work due to peculiarities on os x. i also tried to replace gdb by lldb in the script but that requires different options and probably also chokes on /proc/...

Comment: Try without `/proc/$OPT_p/exe`, I believe it is only needed when the underlying binary is removed, in usual case gdb will find the binary itself just fine

Comment: Fixed the script to not fail in this case

Comment: thanks for taking the time to make it work. the script now runs and apparently does find the binary. but it does unfortunately not produce a usable output for me. the stdout prints something like
  30 ::?? ::?? ::?? ::?? ::?? ::?? ::?? ::?? ::?? ::?? ::?? ::?? ::?? ::?? ::?? ::?? and the trace file i specify looks like this: 0x000000010ecbe1d8 in ?? ()

Thread 1 (Thread 0x1603 of process 83698):
#0  0x000000010ecbe1d8 in ?? ()
#1  0x000000010fe26c90 in ?? ()
#2  0x000000010ecc326e in ?? () etc. the command line was pmp -b atest.p.native -k traces -l 50   to me it seems gdb really isnt working?

Comment: That means it doesn't find any debug info, try compile with -g (i.e. `true: debug`) and update both gdb and ocaml (what is the version?). On the unrelated note it is actually harmful to profile .p.native targets as gprof instrumentation influences runtime behaviour too much, use regular atest.native build. Another possibility is that your system is using clang as default compiler and that doesn't play nice with gdb..

Comment: ah yes, i got confused - now we need debug instead of profiling info. i tried with true: debug in the _tags file for ocamlbuild and also with -cflags -g in the ocamlbuild command line. both times i get the same kind of output as in my previous post.  i did clean the build before. ocaml 4.01, gdb 7.7.1... am i still doing something wrong?

Comment: about clang - yes, clang is the default on os x but why is that relevant for ocaml programs? (newb alert)

Comment: Probably that's not specific to ocaml, something to do with gdb failing to read clang emitted debug info?

Answer (score 1):

since nobody came up with a positive answer, it seems that there is currently no tool available for easy-to-use time profiling of ocaml programs on os x.

Comment: i would be happy to accept a positive answer if there is one

Comment: now there is the spacetime profiler in ocaml 4.04. this may actually do it. have not tried personally.